# Embedding Orbeon XForm in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, orbeon, xforms

We would like to display a form created with Orbeon Forms in an Enterprise Content Management System. The GUI of this system can be extended with JavaScript. Is it possible to design an Orbeon XForms, store it in a kind of repository and later on, query this form in JavaScript so that this form gets rendered in the browser?

I already read the Orbeon documentation and I could only figure out how to embedd XForms in JSP-Pages. Since our ECM-GUI is based on Dojo / JavaScript, this is not possible.

Any ideas are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some users had some success embedding forms with `jQuery.load()`, but at this point this isn't supported. However, this is something that might come in the future, as it is a frequent use case. And for reference, this is the relevant RFE: [#1577](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1577).